# When uploading a large number of images to google drive, A part of them don't appear

Tags: google-drive

When uploading a large number of images to google drive, A part of them don't appear, How to solve this problem, I've tried to wait some hours but that didn't help completely.

Problem with details:

I'm trying to download a dataset from [Kaggle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaggle) into Google drive

The dataset is about 60K images(about 250MB)

When I download it, What I found is about 20K images out of 60K

I've tried to upload images(about 10K) from my PC, the same problem

I'm using web Google drive, windows 10 OS, Google chrome browser

Comment: Welcome @Ahmad! If you edit your question to provide more detail you are more likely to get a helpful answer.   For example, is this on IOS, Android, PC? How many files are you trying to upload? Do you get any messages success or errors.  Are you uploading over wifi or cellular? Etc.  The more we know the more likely it is that you get help.

Comment: I did, The question is better now, Thank you @BlindSpots

Comment: It is difficult to effectively troubleshoot this through a post however I would point out the following resources to help you narrow things down via the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api): [Usage limits](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/limits) [uploads (incl resuming)](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads).  By testing using the API you can control for a number of factors outside your control and also get error messaging returned to you on failures.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because troubleshooting like questions are off-topic in Web Applications SE.

Answer (score 0):

**On a mobile OS (e.g. Android)**

> *In most cases, clearing the cache from a few problematic apps can
> resolve storage or performance issues.
> https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/clear-cache-android/*

**On desktop**

> *Often, Google Drive and Docs (including Sheets and Slides) can fail to work properly. It can either be issues related to making your files and documents work offline or a simple case of the web apps failing to load altogether. And for the majority of issues, clearing the cache is often the best solution.
> https://www.guidingtech.com/clear-cache-google-drive-docs/*

**Smaller batches**

Finally, try removing the images, and re-uploading in smaller batches.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I think the problem is with Google drive, since I don't only try to show my images in the web page, I am loading them to google colab and google colab only finds about 23K (Supposed to find 60K)